# Laravel - Larabook Tutorial:Users. Codeception does see new record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, codeception

I am having trouble getting my codeception test to pass in the larabook tutorials.  I am working through Episode 8: [Users](https://laracasts.com/series/build-a-laravel-app-from-scratch/episodes/8) but having trouble with my codeception test passing.  Even with correcting my code from the video and adding the remember i get the same error.

```
There was 1 failure:

---------
1) Failed to perform actions and see result in SignUpCept (/home/vagrant/larabook/tests/functional/SignUpCept.php)
Couldn't see record "users",{"username":"JohnDoe","email":"john@example.com"}:
Couldn't find users with {"username":"JohnDoe","email":"john@example.com"}

Scenario Steps:
12. I see record "users",{"username":"JohnDoe","email":"john@example.com"}
11. I see "Welcome to Larabook"
10. I see current url equals ""
9 . I click "Sign Up","input[type="submit"]"
8 . I fill field "Password Confirmation:","demo"
7 . I fill field "Password:","demo"
6 . I fill field "Email:","john@example.com"


FAILURES!                            
Tests: 1, Assertions: 3, Failures: 1.
```

Below are my files creating this records. Can someone help me debug this error?

SignUpCept.php

```
$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
$I->am('a guest');
$I->wantTo('perform actions and see result');

$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->click('Sign Up!');
$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/register');

$I->fillField('Username:', 'JohnDoe');
$I->fillField('Email:', 'john@example.com');
$I->fillField('Password:', 'demo');
$I->fillField('Password Confirmation:', 'demo');
$I->click('Sign Up', 'input[type="submit"]');

$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('');
$I->see('Welcome to Larabook');
$I->seeRecord('users', [
    'username' => 'JohnDoe',
    'email' => 'john@example.com'
]);
```

Migration

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }

}
```

User.php

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;


class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * Which fields may be mass assigned?
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'name', 'password'];

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
}
```

RegistrationController.php

```
class RegistrationController extends \BaseController
{

    /**
     * Show a form to register a user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('registration.create');
    }


    /**
     * Create a new larabook user
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function store()
    {
        User::create(
            Input::only('username', 'email', 'password')
        );

        return Redirect::home();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your User.php..

```
/**
 * Which fields may be mass assigned?
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['username', 'name', 'password'];
```

it should be

```
protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];
```

Comment: Thank you. you were correct.  Rookie mistake on my part.  Really appreciate the help